# cosmos cannot delete the duplicate uuid

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

***Hello I post this little message to know if it is possible to delete***

The model is as below:

Create Log data

```json
{
    "publisherID": "",
    "managerID": "",
    "mediaID": "",
    "type": "",
    "ip": "",
    "userAgent": "",
    "playerRes": "",
    "title": "",
    "playerName": "",
    "videoTimeCode": 0,
    "geo": {
        "country": "",
        "region": "",
        "city": "",
        "ll": []
    },
    "date": "",
    "uuid": "",
    "id": ""
}
```

Select all log data: `SELECT * FROM a`

```json
[
    {
        "publisherID": "{ID}",
        "mediaID": "{ID}",
        "type": "Load",
        "ip": "67.69.69.41",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:91.0) Gecko/91.0 Firefox/91.0",
        "parentReferrer": "link.com",
        "title": "title here",
        "playerName": "page",
        "videoTimeCode": 0,
        "geo": {
            "country": "CA",
            "region": "Ontario",
            "city": "Guelph",
            "ll": [
                43.5588,
                -80.3004
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

[SQL-QUERY]: 01 - does not work because there are always duplicate uuids

1. I want to have all the requests of type progress `type: 'Progress'`
2. Organize progress `type` data by minute according to the date

```sql
SELECT COUNT(c.uuid) as total,
left(c.date,16) as time
FROM c
WHERE c.mediaID = '{ID}'
AND (c.date BETWEEN '2021-08-02T14:48:00.000Z' AND '2021-09-03T14:48:00.000Z')
GROUP BY c.uuid, left(c.date, 16)
```

```json
[
    {
        "total": 9,
        "time": "2021-09-03T14:07"
    },
    {
        "total": 40,
        "time": "2021-09-02T12:51"
    },
    {
        "total": 51,
        "time": "2021-09-02T12:50"
    }
]
```

[SQL-QUERY]: 02 - cosmos error !

> Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'DISTINCT'.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.uuid) as total, left(c.date,16) as time
FROM c
WHERE c.mediaID = 'ckpwphqbj10852aav7ib0713o8'
AND (c.date BETWEEN '2021-08-02T14:48:00.000Z' AND '2021-09-03T14:48:00.000Z')
GROUP BY c.uuid, left(c.date, 16)
```

*I want to delete duplicate uuids and then group unique uuids by date*

Comment: You cannot delete any content via the query language; you need to use the API (or language-specific Cosmos DB SDK) for any operation other than `SELECT`. You would need to execute your query to find your duplicate UUIDs, and then choose which documents to delete. Also: question, as written, doesn't really show an example of duplicate UUIDs.

Comment: Your latest edits removed important formatting and introduced unneeded tags (`[sql-server]` is unrelated to Cosmos DB, and `[database]` is unneeded). I fixed your formatting (including making your queries readable). Please be mindful of these things.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

counting `distinct` uuid:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct c.uuid) as total, left(c.date,16) as time 
FROM c 
WHERE c.postID = '155478' 
AND (c.date BETWEEN '2021-08-02T14:48:00.000Z' AND '2021-09-03T14:48:00.000Z') 
GROUP BY left(c.date, 16)
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the topic of deletion (which cannot be done via query language).